# Can this linear space be spanned by probability densities?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Update**: This question is roughly whether the space $L$ defined below by finite number of linear constraints is finite dimensional. If so, can this space be generated by probability densities of the space? It was very obvious in the $X$ finite case as the whole $V$ was finite dimensional in that case. It looks finite dimensionality of $L$ should be obvious as $L$ is determined by finite number of linear constraints. But I do not know how to go about proving it.

---

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $V$ be the vector space of all measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and let $$L=\left\{p\in V:\int pf_i\,d\mu=a_i, i=1,\dots,k\right\} $$ where $f_i\in V$ are independent and $a_i$ are some fixed scalars. Assume that $L$ has at least one strictly positive function $p^*$ (i.e., $p^*(x)>0$ for all $x$) such that $\int p^*\, d\mu<\infty$.

My question is, can then every probability density $p\in L$ be written as a linear combination of some fixed $k$ number of probability densities $p_1,\dots,p_k\in L$? By probability density I mean non negative and integrate to $1$.

The answer is yes when $X$ is finite and $\mu$ is the counting measure (in this case $V$ can just be thought of as a finite dimensional Euclidean space and that the elements of $V$ can be thought of finite dimensional vectors).Following is the proof:

We start with a basis $q_1,\dots,q_k$ of $L$ where $q_1=p^*$. Then we choose scalars $\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k$ so that $p_i=\alpha_i p^*+q_i$ for $i=2,\dots,k$ are all vectors with non negative components. Then with $p_1=p^*$, after normalizing if needed, $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$ would generate $L$.

Comment: $L$ is not a linear space but an [affine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space). $k$ appearing in the definition of $L$ is something like co-dimension of $L$ rather than dimension of $L$. Moreover, in general $L$ could be infinite dimensional.

Comment: @Landscape: Let us consider $L=\left\{p\in V:\int pf_i\,d\mu=0, i=1,\dots,k\right\}$ so that $L$ is a linear space. Are you sure $L$ need not be finite dimensional? Can you show by an example? In which case I will accept that as an answer.

Comment: Yes. To guarantee that $\int p f_i d\mu$ make sense, a natural assumption is $p,f_i\in$ [$L^2(X,\mu)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Lebesgue_spaces). In general, $L^2(X,\mu)$ is infinite dimensional. Since $\{p\in L^2(X,\mu):\int p f_i d\mu=0, i=1,\dots,k\}$ is the [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthogonal_complements_and_projections) of a finite dimensional subspace, which is also infinite dimensional in general.

Comment: @Landscape: Can at least the probability densities of $\{p\in L^2(X,\mu):\int p f_i d\mu=0, i=1,\dots,k\}$ be spanned by a finite number of probability densities $p_1,\dots,p_d$ if the above set admits a strictly positive probability density $p^*$?

Comment: The answer is still no. When $L^2(X,\mu)$ is infinite dimensional(it is equivalent to that the range of $\mu$ is not a finite set), your set is always infinite dimensional, because it is the orthogonal complement of a finite dimensional subspace spanned by $f_1,\dots,f_k$. This fact has nothing to do with whether some strictly positive function is contained in your set or not.

Comment: For example, when $X=[0,1]$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then for $f_n=\sin (n\pi x)$, $n=1,\dots,k$, the constant function $p^*\equiv 1$ is in your set, but your set is infinite dimensional, because $\sin (n\pi x)$, $\forall n>k$ and  $\cos (n\pi x)$, $\forall n\ge 1$ are linearly independent and contained in your set.